# How to rig bones for head and attach it to the model so that the head turns with the bone

Tags: rigging

[image: Screenshot]

The existing rig doesn't move/deform the head.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RM5W4aen0HiJqpmfWP6yiaHMy5S-9uL1/view?usp=sharing

Blender project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TcJiX2N7iK_e6G54ZoxmBmtakF2zZUQo/view?usp=sharing

I used Mixamo, so it changed the bones.

Here is original project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MnWMpi-9CXsfRhJ0dvfKhWYSIORnLx--?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to have each bone "assigned" to the mesh with weight painting. The easiest way to do is is to have Blender do it for you.

In object mode, select the mesh, and then the armature. (the order matters)  Then, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent the armature to the mesh.  Use the option, "with automatic weights".  Please note that will clear all previous weight assignments.

I hope that works for you!

Comment: Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones and after this error I can move every bone except head bones

Comment: These videos might be of help to you: [2 MINUTES to teach bascis of Rigging and Weight Painting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q971pXDxF48) [Understanding Weight Paint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Q0vXf9Ni_4)

Comment: On the mesh, you need to have a vertex group for each bone in your armature, so each bone can deform it by however much you painted it.

Comment: But how to fix this error?

Comment: I have no clue.
At this point, I would start fresh with the rig, but other than that, I don't know.  I'm sorry I wasn't able to help you fix this!